# a proposition in the construction of the Borel measures on the real line

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In the construction of the Borel measures on the real line, the following proposition is used in Folland's Real Analysis:

[image]

Here is my **question**:

> If one replaces $(a_j,b_j]$ with $[a_j,b_j)$, would the proposition still be true?

Comment: If we also assume that $F$ needs is left-continuous instead of right continuous, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also need to change the hypothesis "$F$ is right continuous" by "$F$ is left-continuous".

Let's give a counter-example, i.e., a function $F$ which is right-continuous, not left continuous, and for which the associated $\mu_0$ (defined as $\mu_0(\bigcup_{j=1}^n[a_j,b_j))=\sum_{j=1}^n[F(b_j)-F(a_j)]$) is not a premeasure.

Let $F(x)=x$ if $x<0$ and $F(x)=x+1$ if $x\geq 0$. Then
$[-1,0)=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty[-\frac{1}{n},-\frac{1}{n+1})$. However,
$$\mu_0[-1,0)=F(0)-F(-1)=0+1-(-1)=2,$$
but
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\mu_0[-\frac{1}{n},-\frac{1}{n+1})=\sum_{j=1}^\infty F(-\frac{1}{n+1})-F(-\frac{1}{n})=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=1$$
where the last equality is obtained because we have a telescopic sum.

---

We showed that the hypothesis "$F$ is left-continuous" for $\mu_0$ as above to be a premeasure. To show that this is indeed true, you can apply the theorem as stated in the book to $G(x)=-F(-x)$, and then transfering the measure we obtain by the Theorem via the map $x\mapsto -x$.